# Host prestashop (with single Shop, no multi shop) Back office in different server

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, prestashop, backoffice

**Host Prestashop (having single Shop, no multi shop) Back office in different server/EC2**

I tried to dig more about this, but the only solution I got is a multi-shop.

is there anybody achieved this with any type of server?

**What problem I am trying to fix?**

BO should not be down when FO is down. so I am moving BO to separate EC2 server. so that the operation does not get affected.

Comment: who ever added a -1 can you please add commnet and explain why.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I did vote to close because it isn't a programming question. Possibly [sf] might be a suitable place to have asked (but read their help first)

Answer (score 1):

What you say doesn't make too much sense to me,
mainly because FO and BO share the same codebase (and the same database of course).

So what you have to do to avoid downtime is a classic HA approach to horizontal-scale the whole application (web / database) in order to have failover :

**WEB:**

- Split the web in several servers
- Put a load balancer (ie HAproxy) in front
- Use a shared filesystem (NFS) in all web nodes

This way you can decide to route web requests to certain servers (and handle BO requests to the servers you decide by checking the admin url , for instance).

In the Prestashop backoffice you'll find a *"multi-front optimization"* option that allows you to manage the cache properly with this scaled architecture.

**DB:**

You'll need replication and failover too.

Based on my experience I recommend a Master/Slave topology and a MySQL proxy in front
(this will guarantee failover by promoting Slave to Master if Master node goes down).

Note that even if prestashop natively supports MySQL Slaves array (in **config/db_Slave_server.inc.php** file) ,
you won't have great performance because only some legacy queries will go through the Slave.

Looks like it is also possible to use a multi-Master architecture with some hacks because of non consecutive auto-increments between servers,

See : https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/15019

This way you can scale more easily , but you'll end up with offset-ed IDs in your products, categories etc. (so I never tried this in production)

So, summarizing, you will have to "fight" with the classic problems that come with a HA architecture...

By the way , this is the official ""documentation"" you will find about horizontal scaling Prestashop :

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/scale/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciate it.  I had done the loadbalancer and DB replication is not possible in the Aurora AWS DB. I have seen people hosting the ssame code with different BO URL, so I am sure this is possible. the main Problem is the Traffic is very unexpected similar to black friday in the MALL. and it is un predictable as well. e.g. 50K concurrent users, for buying a rare product. i just wante to make sure that BO works and the operations does not get affected.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never used aws so i can't help you about their architecture, I've worked a lot with different cloud instances and/or classic Centos VMs, anyway if you get something good and you want to share , I would like to know since splitting PS FO <->  BO on huge workloads would be great to achieve.